# Horizontal two column page printing issue

Tags: html, css, printing

I have made a report that is two columns based and layout horizontal. I am trying to add page numbers but not working. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/rz763cab/1/)

```
   /*Page Number*/
    @page main-print-page:right {
        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page);
            font-size: 11pt;
            color: grey;
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

We can see in the above screenshot, a horizontal page and two columns. Here should show page 1 and page 2 for per column

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
 div.main-print-page{
         counter-reset: page;
       }
      .page{
         position:relative;
       }
      .page:nth-child(even):after {       

          counter-increment: page;
          content: counter(page);

      }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: I have modified @Sfili_81